# Pythagorean Triples Efficiency

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to create a function that takes a list of integers and returns whether or not there is a Pythagorean triple inside the list. For example, `[3, 5, 7, 4]` returns `True` since 3, 4, 5 is a Pythagorean triple. So far I have this (in Python):

```
def containsPythagoreanTriple(a): 
    for i in xrange(len(a)): #square the numbers
        num = a[i]
        a[i] = num**2
    a = sorted(a)
    for start in xrange(len(a)): #compare every pair
        for i in xrange(start+1, len(a)):
            if a[start] + a[i] in a:
                return True
    return False
```

Is there a way to make this even more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that could be improved in that code, as far as performance is concerned.

The current implementation is `O(N**3)` (where `N` is `len(a)`), as you check if the list of squares contains each sum of each pair of items. Membership testing in a `list` is `O(N)` and there are `O(N**2)` pairs to test.

You can improve this bit by using a `set` rather than a list to hold your items. Testing item membership in a `set` is `O(1)`, so you'll get an `O(N**2)` algorithm this way.

There are some further changes that might speed things up a bit, but none of them change the asymptotic complexity any further. To start with, you don't need to call `sorted`, since you are going to test every pair of items anyway. You can also use a set comprehension to do your squaring, rather than overwriting the original `a` list. Finally, you can use `itertools.combinations` to generate your pairs of squares, and `any` on a generator expression to test if their sums are in the set.

Here's some more optimized code using the same algorithm:

```
import itertools

def containsPythagoreanTriple(a):
    squares = {x*x for x in a} # set comprehension
    return any(x+y in squares for x,y in itertools.combinations(squares))
```

There might still be further room to optimize things a bit more, by changing the algorithm in more fundamental ways. You don't need to test every pair for instance, since some values can never be the "short leg" of a triangle (the largest value, for instance). You could filter the squares passed to `itertools.combinations` so that they include only those less than or equal to `max(squares)-min(squares)`. I'm not sure if this would be worth while unless your list of values gets pretty large.

Answer (score 1):

same, but little bit differently

```
import math    
def tripple(array): 
    array = sorted(array)
    for start in xrange(len(array)): #compare every pair
      m = array[start]
      for i in xrange(start+1, len(array)):
        n = array[i]
        if math.sqrt(n*n+m*m) in array:
          print m, n, math.sqrt(n*n+m*m)

array=[4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 5, 9, 8, 10, 12, 15, 40, 41];     
tripple(array);
```